# Filtering our potential duplicate items in search results with mysql or sphinx

Tags: mysql, duplicates, innodb, sphinx

I think this is a long-shot....

My database has the following fields: `title, description, date, price, hash`

At present I generate an MD5 hash like so `md5($title.$desc.$date.$price)` and place it in the `hash` field for each item, so that when a new item is added to the database I have an easy and *fairly* reliable way of knowing whether an item with the same details already exists in the database.

What I would like to do is expand this, so the match process is a little more fuzzy. The reason for this is that I'm seeing lots of duplicate items in the database where the description may be only one or two characters different, or the price might be slightly different.

The database is large (3mill rows) and is INNODB. I also have Sphinx at my disposal if this offers a way of filtering out similar results when they are returned from searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well Sphinx (or other 'search engine') would need a similar 'hash' computing to be able to remove duplicates at query time.

Where sphinx might help you, when you insert an item into the database, use sphinx to run a search on the database for similar items. You could get a 'ranked' list of potential duplicates. If the top item has a high score, you could say its suffiently similar, and then store that fact in the databse.

(How I do it, is have a second column on the table called 'grouper', by default it just duplicates the primary key of the item. But if a duplicate is found, instead its changed to the PK of the item it duplicates. Can then just run a mysql (or sphinx!) GROUP BY on that grouper column)

Answer (score 0):

You could use SOUNDEX on the description (used to cope with slightly different spellings of words).

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex

For the price, if you round it to the nearest 10 (or whatever is reasonable) before creating the MD5 that should cope with small differences.